# how to Find value from DropDownList

Tags: c#, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

i try to get a value from dropdownList but i have this error "{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"} i  need to post this value because it' an id of my table "page"
this is the code of controller :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<SelectListItem> SelectListItem = new List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>();
    foreach (Pages item in DbContext.Pages)
    {    
        SelectListItem SelectList = new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = item.PageName,
            Value = item.IdPage.ToString()
        };
        SelectListItem.Add(SelectList);
    }
    Pages pagesmodel = new Pages();
    pagesmodel.PagesA = SelectListItem;
    return View(pagesmodel);
}

   // this is the problem
   var selected = page.PagesA.Select(item => 
       item.Value.Equals(page.SelectedPages));
   return RedirectToAction("Details","manage",new { id=selected});
}
```

and this is the code of my model :

```
public class PagesModel  
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PagesA { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> SelectedPages { get; set; }
}
```

thanks;

Comment: In `PagesModel`, the `IEnumerable<string> SelectedPages` is an `IEnumerable`. Yet, the line of code you are having trouble with has an `Equals` operator. Is that expected?

You cannot perform an `Equals` operation on an IEnumerable (`SelectedPages`) and a string(`SelectListItem.Value`)

Comment: i need to get the value of a dropdownlist cheeked .. whene i debug solution i have a result in selected page but page.selectedpage it's null

Answer (score 0):

```
// this is the problem 
var selected = page.PagesA.Select(item => item.Value.Equals(page.SelectedPages)
```

This returns list of boolean values which is not desired output (you need id).

I believe that you need to change your classes in this way:

```
public class PagesModel 
{ 
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PagesA { get; set; } 
     public string SelectedPage { get; set; } 
 }
```

And

```
var selected = page.PagesA.Where(item => item.Equals(page.SelectedPage);
```

Comment: thanks, but i have the some error {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"}

Answer (score 0):

we nee to return a string to a variable not a IEnumerable .. so the solution we need to change a class to :

```
public class PagesModel 
{ 
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PagesA { get; set; } 
     public string SelectedPage { get; set; } 
 }
```

and in controller:

```
  var selected =page.SelectedPage;
     return RedirectToAction("Details","manage",new { id=selected});
    }
```

Thanks all,